# Como somar valores de um model e inserir o resultado em outro utilizando Django?

Tags: python, django

Possuo esse model que tem como objetivo cadastrar os serviços disponíveis e seus respectivos valores:

```
class Servico(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField('Nome do serviço', max_length=255)
    preco = models.DecimalField('Preço do serviço', decimal_places=2)
    data_cadastro = models.DateTimeField('Data de cadastro',auto_now_add=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome
```

Criei outro model chamado venda, onde poderá ser cadastrados vários serviços para uma única venda. Eu gostaria de inserir a soma dos preços dos serviços dentro de `valor_total`

```
class Venda(models.Model):
    FORMPAG_CHOICES = (
        ('CC', 'Cartão de Crédito'),
        ('CD', 'Cartão de Crédito'),
        ('D', 'Dinheiro'),
        ('T', 'Transferência (Entre contas/PIX)')
    )

    forma_pag = models.CharField('Forma de pagamento', max_length=2, choices=FORMPAG_CHOICES)
    cliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente, verbose_name='Cliente', on_delete='models.PROTECT')
    servicos = models.ManyToManyField(Servico, verbose_name='Serviços prestados')
    data_cadastro = models.DateTimeField('Data da venda',auto_now_add=True)
    valor_total = # É aqui onde quero inserir o valor total da venda
```

Comment: Model.py cadastra no banco, o que vc qr fazer é realizado via forms.py e com javascript. Como faz um tempinho que mandou essa pergunta, atualiza a pergunta com o que vc conseguiu até agora.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talvez criar uma property no model de Venda para sempre calcular isso pra ti. Algo tipo abaixo:

```py
class Venda(models.Model):
  # ...

  @property
  def valor_total():
    servicos = self.servicos.all() # aplicar filtros padroes se precisar
    preco_total = 0.00
    for servico in servicos:
       preco_total += servico.preco
    return preco_total
```

o `@property` é praticamente para conseguir chamar `venda.valor_total` e nao precisa chamar `venda.valor_total()`

Espero que isso já ajude.

Comment: Só não entendi como é inserido no banco :/

Comment: Teria que inserir no valor de cada serviço. Esse metodo ai é realmente só para pegar agora para inserir teria que salvar nos preços de cada serviço, que dai quando pegar já pega certinho.